# How do I jump back in history directly, I don't want the go() function to call back() multiple times

Tags: html, history.js

I'm using staterouter.js over the top of history.js. When I go back multiple pages, history.js internally calls back() the respective amount of times - and this is not desirable in my situation, because I have handler which is called for each intermediate call to back()

```
History.go = function(index,queue){
    //History.debug('History.go: called', arguments);

    // Prepare
    var i;

    // Handle
    if ( index > 0 ) {
        // Forward
        for ( i=1; i<=index; ++i ) {
            History.forward(queue);
        }
    }
    else if ( index < 0 ) {
        // Backward
        for ( i=-1; i>=index; --i ) {
            History.back(queue);
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Error('History.go: History.go requires a positive or negative integer passed.');
    }

    // Chain
    return History;
};
```

Is there any way around this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own function which I call when I need the behaviour as described above. It requires my own application layer implementation to be able to ignore routing callbacks for all but one of the abs(qty) history movements.

```
goDirect = function (qty) {
    if (qty === -1 || qty === 1) {
        router.go(qty);
        return;
    }

    ignoreNavigations = Math.abs(qty) - 1;
    router.go(qty);
};
```

The following code is used as the first line of route handlers:

```
if (ignoreNavigations-- > 0) return;
```

I did try simply setting a RouteEnabled flag to false when calling go(abs(qty)-1), before setting the flag back to true and calling a final go(-1), however it appears that response to the navigations occur asynchronously, and therefore I changed the implementation to the above code, rather than try and use timers and get all messy.